# Looking for a tool to quickly test C# format strings

Tags: c#, formatting, string

I am constantly forgetting what the special little codes are for formatting .NET strings. Either through ToString() or using String.Format(). Alignment, padding, month vs. minute (month is uppercase M?), abbreviation vs. full word, etc. I can never remember.

I have the same problem with regexes, but luckily there's [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to help me out. It's awesome.

Is there a tool like Expresso for experimenting with formatted strings on standard types like DateTime and float and so on?

Comment: http://www.mobzystems.com/online/format-tester/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PowerShell works great for testing format strings. From PowerShell you can load your assembly and work with the objects and methods you want to test.  You could also just create a string on the command line and test out different formatting options.

You can use the static method from the string class:

```
$teststring = 'Currency - {0:c}.  And a date - {1:ddd d MMM}.  And a plain string - {2}'
[string]::Format($teststring, 160.45, Get-Date, 'Test String')
```

Or PowerShell has a built in format operator

```
$teststring = 'Currency - {0:c}.  And a date - {1:ddd d MMM}.  And a plain string - {2}'
$teststring -f 160.45, Get-Date, 'Test String'
```

Comment: just an fyi, I was using 'Get-Date' function and powershell complained about putting a function in there, when I forced the value into a variable and then used the variable after the -f it worked fine

Answer (score 11):

I just found this:

http://rextester.com/

Simply paste in your format string, and run the code.

It would also be simple enough to create a windows or console project that does exactly that.

Comment: This is the best answer and it proves that the question is perfectly valid

Answer (score 6):

[Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/) is a great tool in general for quick small app testing. Instead of cluttering your Visual Studio with a million ConsoleApplication79 projects, just use this. I have it and use it constantly.

Answer (score 4):

[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) is a great tool that handles this sort of thing brilliantly, even though it's tangential to its primary function (of troubleshooting Linq syntax).

Just enter the expression with the language selector set to "C# Expression" (or "VB.net Expression") and the database set to "None." For example:

```
String.Format("{0:d}-{1:d}", new DateTime(2012, 1, 6), null)
```

When you press Run, you'll get the result:

```
1/6/2012-
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#FormatDesigner

Comment: Pretty close but it's lacking the alignment stuff that you get outside of ToString(). I like that it's updated in real-time though.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You could use the [Snippy](http://jasonhaley.com/blog/archive/2008/11/23/142521.aspx) plugin for Reflector to run little code snippets.</strike>

Looks like the link is dead - just use [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)!

Answer (score 0):

Just another simple utility, avaliable on MSDN: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=209564, description is:

> an application that enables you to apply format strings to either numeric or date and time values and displays the result string.

But you need to compile it by yourself.